# gruntjs - jquery-ui-touch-punch not working in grunt prod on iPad

Tags: ipad, jquery-ui, gruntjs

I've an application developed using reuire, backbone, jquery, jquery-ui,  jquery-ui-touch-punch and hammer.

The application has 2 parts: `<li>` elements which are draggable and a `<div>` which is droppable area. The use case is to drag an `<li>` and drop it on a `<div>`. `<div>` is working as a timeline which has zoom and pan functionality.

Zoom and pan is implemented using hammer.js to work it well on iPad. For desktop browsers, it is implemented using `mousewheel` and `mousedown` events.

When I build the application using `grunt dist:local -force`, it works fine on desktop and on iPad browser. But when I build it using `grunt dist:prod -force`, it works fine on desktop browser but stops dragging of jquery-ui elements on iPad.

Please find below the configuration file.

```
requirejs.config({
  shim: {
    jquery: {
      exports: '$'
    },
    underscore:{
        exports: '_'
    },
    backbone:{
        deps    : ['jquery', 'underscore'],
        exports : 'Backbone'
    },
    createjs: {
        exports : 'createjs'
    },
    d3:{
        deps    : ['jquery', 'underscore'],
        exports : 'd3'
    },
    sinon: {
        exports : 'sinon'
    },
    'jquery-ui': {
        deps   : ['jquery'],
        exports : '$'
    },
    'jquery-ui-core': {
        deps   : ['jquery'],
        exports : '$'
    },
    'jquery-ui-widget': {
        deps   : ['jquery-ui-core'],
        exports : '$'
    },
    'jquery-ui-mouse': {
        deps   : ['jquery-ui-widget'],
        exports : '$'
    },
    'jquery-ui-slider': {
        deps   : ['jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-widget', 'jquery-ui-mouse'],
        exports : '$'
    },
    'touch-punch': {
       deps   : ['jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-widget', 'jquery-ui-mouse'],
       exports : '$'
    },

    'transitjs' : {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: '$'
    },
    hammerjs: {
        exports : 'Hammer'
    }
},
  paths: {
    env         : 'environment/local',

    text        : '../../../bower_components/requirejs-text/text',

    jquery      : '../../../bower_components/jquery/jquery',
    'jquery-ui' : "../../../bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui",
    'jquery-ui-core' : "../../../bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery.ui.core",
    'jquery-ui-widget' : "../../../bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery.ui.widget",
    'jquery-ui-mouse' : "../../../bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery.ui.mouse",
    'jquery-ui-slider': "../../../bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery.ui.slider",
    underscore  : '../../../bower_components/underscore/underscore',
    backbone    : '../../../bower_components/backbone/backbone',
    check       : '../../../bower_components/check-js/check.min',
    d3          : '../../../bower_components/d3/d3.min',
    createjs    : '../../../bower_components/createjs/index', 


    'astro-lib': "../../../bower_components/astro-lib/app/scripts/astro-lib",
    'histogramjs': "../../../bower_components/histogramjs",
    'transitjs': "../../../bower_components/transitjs/jquery.transit",   
    'sinon'       : "../../../test/libs/sinon-1.4.2",

    'hammerjs'    : "../../../bower_components/hammerjs/dist/hammer.min",

    'touch-punch':"../../../bower_components/jqueryui-touch-punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch"//,

    //'polyfill-typedarray'    : "../../../bower_components/polyfill/typedarray"
  }
});
```

and `bower.json`

```
{
  "name": "timescaler",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "1.8.3",
    "requirejs": "~2",
    "requirejs-text": "~2",
    "mocha": "~1.6",
    "chai": "~1.3",
    "chai-jquery": "~1.1.1",
    "almond": "~0.2",
    "backbone": "~0.9.2",
    "jquery-ui": "~1.10.3",
    "underscore": "~1.4.2",  
    "check-js": "~0.1.0",
    "flat-ui-official": "",
    "font-awesome": "~3.2.1",
    "d3":"~3.2.7",
    "createjs": "http://code.createjs.com/createjs-2013.02.12.min.js",
    "jqueryui-touch-punch": "",    
    "hammerjs": "~1.0.5",
    "polyfill": "https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill.git",
    "astro-lib": "git@github.com:SmartSparrow/astro-lib.git",
    "pipit": "https://github.com/SmartSparrow/pipit-js.git"
  }
}
```

Is there any issue with jquery-ui-touch-punch on `grunt dist:prod -force`? Why is it working fine with `grunt dist:local -force` on desktop browsers?

Comment: We need to see your gruntfile to tell if anything is wrong with it.

Comment: It was the issue of ordering to add `jquery-ui` and `touch-punch` on page. I added `touch-punch` before `jquery-ui` and so it was not working in `grunt dist:prod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the issue of ordering to add `jquery-ui` and `touch-punch` on page. I added `touch-punch` before `jquery-ui` and so it was not working in `grunt dist:prod`.